# faces change geometry at certain viewing angles

Tags: javascript, three.js

When using the orbit camera around the meshes in my scene some of the face geometries change shape at certain viewing angles.[here's a gif of what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Dcis.gif)

this can also be seen on the Three.js example [camera/orthographic2](https://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_camera_orthographic2), much more noticeable on the 12mm lens size.

Just really wanna know how to fix this or if it's a bug!

Comment: It has something to do with the triangulation of the model. Did you create the model in modelling software? If so, post it here so we can take a look (preferably in a format I can open in 3dsmax)

Comment: they are just BoxGeometry() from three.js, no external models. @2pha

Comment: Are you using `CanvasRenderer`? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266931/disappearing-objects-three-js-canvasrenderer/23276601#23276601).

Comment: @WestLangley That fixed it! thank you very much, sir!